# How to get photo from drwable and upload and retrieve it into parse Android

Tags: android, parsing

i want make a code that can getjpg Images from drwable folder and upload it to parse and how to retrieve it into list view

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert your drawable to Bitmap;

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                           R.drawable.icon_resource);
```

Now you can convert your bitmap to string by using below code

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Then send this encodedImage as a String and in your server you will need to decode it in order to get the image itself.